# Delay between storyboard default properties and my custom properties on iOS 11 + XCode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but I cannot find a solution. The thing is I have a custom UITextField with custom properties, for instance, background color, and I reuse this control in my storyboards. The problem is when I run the app on the simulator or device, there is a little delay at runtime between the default storyboard values and the values I set in my custom control. For example, if I drag a UITextField to my view controller in my storyboard, leave all the properties to their default values and just set my custom control class in the Identity Inspector, when I run the code in either the simulator or my device, I see a display delay between the default white background color for this UITextField and the custom one set in my custom class. Is someone experiencing this issue?
Here a snippet of my class:

```
import UIKit
import SwifterSwift


@IBDesignable
class TextField: UITextField {

    // MARK: - Properties
    // Left padding for text and placeholder
    @IBInspectable var textPadding = Constants.Views.textFieldTextPadding {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Property Overrides
    // change the default height
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        contentSize.height = Constants.Views.textFieldHeight
        return contentSize
    }


    // MARK: - Initializers
    // IBDesignables require both of these inits, otherwise we'll
    // get an error: IBDesignable View Rendering times out.
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772729/ibdesignable-view-rendering-times-out
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupDefaults()
    }

    // This attribute hides `init(coder:)` from subclasses
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupDefaults()
    }

    // MARK: - Method Overrides
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupDefaults()
    }

     //provides left padding for the text
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return super.textRect(forBounds: bounds).insetBy(dx: textPadding, dy: 0)
    }

    // provides left padding for the editing text
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }

    // provides left padding for the placeholder text
    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }


    // MARK: - Private Methods
    func setupDefaults() {

        // set default font
        font = Constants.Views.textFieldFont

        // set default colors
        textColor = Constants.Views.textFieldTextColor
        tintColor = textColor // default for image tinting and cursor color
        backgroundColor = Constants.Views.textFieldBackgroundColor

        // set border style
        borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none

        // rounded corners first, order matters if setting shadow
        cornerRadius = Constants.Views.cornerRadius

        // set the shadow
        setShadow(color: Constants.Views.shadowColor, radius: Constants.Views.shadowRadius,
                  offset: Constants.Views.shadowOffset, opacity: Constants.Views.shadowOpacity)

        // clear button
        clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

        // show a Done button in the keyboard to dismiss it
        showDoneButton = true
    }

}
```

Comment: anyone here please?

Comment: I figured the problem out, the delay was because I disabled the splash screen and it was the effect of the system taking my main view controller as the splash screen and making an animation to himself at runtime.