# Is it possible to update programmatically a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I made a class called Container with subclass UIView.

In a UIViewController, I use a subclass of my Container class, which I call LoginContainer.

The code for the Container class is

```
@IBDesignable open class Container: UIView {
    weak var controller: UIViewController!
    var constraintsOK: Bool = false
    
    @IBInspectable open var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable open var borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth / UIScreen.main.scale
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable open var shadow: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if shadow {
                addShadow()
                setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Initializers

    // IBDesignables require both of these inits, otherwise we'll get an error: IBDesignable View Rendering times out.
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772729/ibdesignable-view-rendering-times-out
    
    /// Pour les initializers, ne pas appeler customInit dans InterfaceBuilder
    ///  car déjà appelé dans PrepareforInterfaceBuilder
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        #if !TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
        customInit()
        #endif
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        #if !TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
        customInit()
        #endif
    }
    
    // MARK: - Build control

    override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        customInit()
    }
    
    /// Overriden method must call super.customInit().
    open func customInit() {
        addBorder()
        /// L'ombre, s'il y en a est ajoutée dans layoutSubviews
    }
    
    /// Must be overriden when subclassed
    open func setConstraints() {}
    
    /// Adds a border to the control.
    open func addBorder() {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth / UIScreen.main.scale

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735623/uilabel-layer-cornerradius-negatively-impacting-performance
        if layer.shouldRasterize == false {
            layer.masksToBounds = true
            layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            layer.shouldRasterize = true
        }
    }
    
    open func addShadow() {
        /// Attention, la couleur de fonds ne doit pas être à transparent, sinon on voit toute l'ombre en transparence
        clipsToBounds = false
        let shadowRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: bounds.width-10, height: bounds.height-15)
        layer.shadowColor = CGColor(red: 14/255, green: 47/255, blue: 133/255, alpha: 1)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowRect).cgPath
        layer.shadowRadius = layer.cornerRadius
        
        // https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-shadow-to-a-uiview
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowRect).cgPath
        if layer.shouldRasterize == false {
            layer.masksToBounds = false
            layer.shouldRasterize = true
            layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - LifeCycle
    
    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if !constraintsOK {
            setConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the LoginContainer subclass class is

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class LoginContainer: Container {
    
    override public func setConstraints() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
        if let view = findViewController()?.view {
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        }
        #endif
        if let view = controller?.view {

            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        }
        constraintsOK = true
    }

}
```

And finally the code for the UIViewController is

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: LoginContainer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        container.controller = self
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


}

extension UIView {
    public func findViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let nextResponder = self.next
        if nextResponder is UIViewController {
            return nextResponder as? UIViewController
        } else if nextResponder is UIView {
            return (nextResponder as! UIView).findViewController()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

When I look the storyboard  everything is correct, the constraints of LoginContainer have been correctly updated

[the view LoginContainer is not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SFGw.png)

But when in the storyboard, I selected the LoginContainer view, this what I see

[The view LoginContainer is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QPIW.png)

The selected link of the LoginContainer doesn't reflect the reality

if there are multiple container views included in the contentView, this can become a real problem (think for instance to a keyboard view, where each key is represented by a Container class)

So my question is: Is it possible to update the storyboard by program, or at least have IB showing the correct position when the view is selected?

Comment: This looks like a very unusual approach, and it's not surprising that it doesn't work well with Storyboard / IB. If your goal is to create an `@IBDesignable` view with "self arranging" subviews, your "Container" view should manage its subviews, but the controller should manage the constraints on the "Container" view.

Comment: @DonMag: unless mistaking, if I manage the constraints of LoginContainer in the controller, IB don't show me this view as I want. It seems that the constraints only applied in the running app, but not in the storyboard

Comment: *"IB don't show me this view as I want"* -- correct. When you add a view in IB, it defaults to using auto-resizing mask. Your code ends up giving IB conflicting information. Note that if you add a `UIView`, set its class to your `LoginContainer` class, and then give that view a Leading constraint of 10, IB *will* position the view and its frame as you want. However, if you then drag the view or change its size, you'll be back in the "visual doesn't line up with frame" situation.

Comment: If you explain what your actual goal is, there may be a better approach.

Comment: I don't know very well stackoverflow. Is it possible for me to respond you in an answer, rather than in a comment?

Comment: I made an App with multiple views, tables and detail views, very classical.
It does the job.

But when I begin to make constraints for different orientations in my different views, it's hell. Particularly in cells of table. Very often, Xcode crashes, or if I put a new constraint in a view, for some trait orientation, the other constraints are deleted. Of course I work with inferred subviews

I precise thatI my Xcode version is 13.1 and that my OS version is Big Sur 11.6

Comment: OK - your question, then, is really much more about "How do I properly set constraints for traits / size-classes." Edit this question (or close it and post a new one), with an example of your cell layout and an explanation of what constraints you're having trouble with. I really think that will be a much better approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238775/discussion-between-patrice-rapaport-and-donmag).